# How to delegate task to someone else when task assigned to person is out?

Tags: workflow, delegate

I have a situation where a task is assigned to a person thru workflow. That person is now gone. I know site admin can delegate the task to someone else.

But I would like manager (say from a group "managers" or manager's field) to delegate a task when necessary in the event the task owner is out on ill, vacation, or left the company.

How is it done?

Comment: Check [another thread][1] on SharePoint StackExchange.


  [1]: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/74158/approve-tasks-not-assigned-to-me/74160#74160